# Proving f is not a surjective function.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading a question and it says:
let $f:X \to \mathcal P(X)$ be a function from the set $X$ to $\mathcal P(X)$, where $\mathcal P(X)$ is the power set of $X$.

By taking the set $$Y=\{x \in X: x \notin f(x) \},$$
prove that $f$ is not a surjective function.

I don't actually understand the question a lot, but what I tried is that if $x \in Y$ then $f(x)=(\{1\}, \phi)$ if we take $X=\{1,2\}$ and $f(2)=(\{2\},\phi)$ then there is no $x$ where $f(x)=(\{1,2\})$ then $f$ is not surjective.

I don't know if this is true, and I don't think so.
So what does this question mean, and how would the answer for this be, because I tried a lot for a lot of days to understand it and yet I didn't understand anything!

Comment: Hi! You don't need a mathematical keyboard, you can use Latex (or in this case mathJax) for example \$ \phi \$ where you remove backslashes before the dollar sign gives you $\phi$

Comment: Hint: Consider $ S = \{ i | i \in f(i) \}$ and $ T = X \backslash S$.

Comment: P(X) is the [power set of $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y \in \mathcal P(X)$ (the power set of $X$), so all we have to do to show that $f$ is not surjective, is to show that there is no $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = Y$.

But $Y$ cannot be in the image of $f$, since for any $x \in X$, $Y$ and $f(x)$ disagree on the membership of $x$.
That is, if $x \in Y$, then $x \notin f(x)$, and if $x \notin Y$, then $x \in f(x)$.

Thus $Y \ne f(x)$ for any $x$. Hence $f$ is certainly not surjective.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand how Y€P(X)?

Comment: @Jhon $\mathcal P(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$. $Y$ is defined as those $x \in X$ that satisfy a certain property, so it is a subset of $X$ and thus must be in $\mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: This was a FAQ. Please do not anwer duplicates.